# Possible to create a listbox by click on a button

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, listbox

I will create multiple entry box for user to input, and click on a button that will store all entry value in to a array, entries will be cleared, and then stored user can store another set of entry values.

So this button will do 2 functions:
1: store values in to my array
2: create 1st listbox with values from 1st array

In result, i can end up with multiple sets of array, and each sets of array with its own listbox.

I have not find related guide to this, or 'dynamic create listbox' did not help me. Possible to share examples if this doable.

Comment: You will have to append the values in to a textfile or database to store it or after each time you close your app, it'll get lost

Comment: Please edit your question to include some code that you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow Community.

As far as I understand your question, I have tried this

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def saveClear():
    global entry_list
    listbox = Listbox(root)
    for entry in entry_list:
        listbox.insert(END, entry.get())
        entry.set('')
    listbox.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10)
    
entry_list = []
for _ in range(5):
    ent_var = StringVar()
    ent = Entry(root, textvariable = ent_var)
    entry_list.append(ent_var)
    ent.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10)

but = Button(root, text = 'Save and Clear', command = saveClear)
but.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10)

root.mainloop()
```

**UPDATE:** In order to get the values form a `ListBox()`, you will need to make use of `listvariable` attribute with the target as `Variable()` to store the values as a tuple and use the `.get()` method to get the value of the same.

Here is the updated code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def retrieve(index):    
    global values
    if index == 'all':
        for value in values:
            print(value.get())
    else:
        print(values[index].get())

values = []
def saveClear():
    global entry_list, values
    list_var = Variable()
    listbox = Listbox(root, listvariable = list_var)
    for entry in entry_list:
        listbox.insert(END, entry.get())
        entry.set('')
    values.append(list_var)
    listbox.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10)

entry_list = []
for _ in range(5):
    ent_var = StringVar()
    ent = Entry(root, textvariable = ent_var)
    entry_list.append(ent_var)
    ent.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10)

but = Button(root, text = 'Save and Clear', command = saveClear)
but.pack(padx = 10, pady = 10)

root.mainloop()
retrieve('all') #OR specify the index that you wish to retrieve
```

Here the `retrieve()` is called after the end of `mainloop()`, i.e., it will be executed after the termination of the mainloop, but you can use this function in your code as you require.

Hope it helped. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for this, I did not know how to start with...
I tried to continue with the code, and want to print out values in each listbox.
it is printing out tons of [<tkinter.Listbox object .!listbox>, or [<tkinter.Listbox object .!listbox2> for the second save and exit.

code:
https://pastebin.com/p0pr40fL

Comment: @SCH I just realized that you can't achieve what you are looking for with the suggestion that I had provided earlier, but I have corrected and updated my answer, I hope it works as you expected it to.